# Windows Phone Password Lock Screen Verify

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Good day, can i programatically check if windows phone screen is locked with password.

I need to notify user that he should lock the screen with password due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no way in Windows Phone 7 to check for this information.
Best shot you have is just to remind him to always setup a password, but you can't enforce it.

Comment: Ok, so basically it won't be possible to do on Windows phone 8 aswell ?

Comment: I just developed for Windows Phone 7, not for 8, so I don't know. Please ask a separate question for this. And feel free to mark my answer.